# How to access videos in the Videos of section *warning cute cat videos*

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have created a facebook application called Video Uploader and a company called Test company that can be found here:

https://www.facebook.com/pages/Test-Company/325671224142294?sk=videos

I am just wondering how would I access the videos in the Videos of test company section using the graph api or facebook query language?

On this page https://www.facebook.com/pages/Test-Company/325671224142294?sk=videos it is the video of the bunny rabbit looking thing trying to jump over the yellow hoolahoop that I am trying to access? If anyone can help me out that would be great! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

> I am just wondering how would I access the videos in the Videos of
>   test company section using the graph api or facebook query language?

You can use FQL. See:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/video/

`SELECT vid, owner, title, description, thumbnail_link, embed_html, updated_time, created_time FROM video WHERE owner=PAGEID`